# regexp map /etc/postfix/body_checks unknown regexp option "/"

Tags: postfix

Please help with an hint.

I have implemented into my postfix the following rule:
/https://test/  DISCARD - test

When I try to test it: # postmap -q "https://test" regexp:/etc/postfix/body_checks

postmap: warning: regexp map /etc/postfix/body_checks,: unknown regexp option "/": skipping this rule

So, any ideas how to solve this issue?

Thanks!
Nick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should add it like this:

```
/https:\/\/test/ DISCARD - TEST
```

Comment: Thanks Talal! It works that way. Tricky regexp bull$hit. Btw, I don't get it, why in the world if I have, let's say /free/ discard, why it will discard "free money" as well? How can I limit to discard only free, not free money, for example. Thanks!

Comment: Your welcome. If you use /free/ it will check lines that has free in it but if you want lines that starts with free you should use /^free/ and in both ways it will discard if it has the word money or not. So, you must study spam emails that that come through to you and use regex to your advantage where you can find key similarities and use them whether in header or body checks. 
Also you can try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24706933/regular-expression-to-find-postfix-but-ignore-a-specify-prefix I don’t know if it will work

Comment: Thanks Talal. I really appreciate your help. Regards, Nick.